# Generate several model rows from a date range in rails 5.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate several scheduled events from a date range on selected days input in a form for a specific trainer, The Evento model is:

```
class Evento < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :equipo
  has_many :asistencias, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :asistencias
  scope :done, -> { where(registrado: true) }
  validates :equipo_id, :fecha, :tipoEvento, presence: true
end
```

so I have a view at 'app/views/eventos/forma_prog.html.erb' which includes a form to get the parameters to define the date range like this:

```
<% provide(:title, "Entrenamientos") %>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <h1>Programación de Entrenamientos</h1>

  <%= form_tag(programa_path) do %>
    <% dias = [] %>
    <%= label_tag(:entrenador, "Trainer:") %>
    <%= select_tag :entrenador, 
       options_from_collection_for_select(@entrenadores, "id", "name"), 
       prompt: "Select the trainer", class: 'form-control' %>
    <b>Days:</b>
    <div class="well">
      <% @dias.each_with_index do |day, index| %>
        <%= label_tag day, day, class: "checkbox-inline nopadding"; %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'dias[]', index, checked = false, class: 
         "nopadding" %>  |
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= label_tag(:inicio, "Starting Date:") %>
    <%= date_field_tag :inicio, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= label_tag(:final, "Ending Date:") %>
    <%= date_field_tag :final, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Create events", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

It works fine and returns params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"10BsOFEsCvO...==",
 "entrenador"=>"2",
 "dias"=>["2", "4"],    # Being Tuesday and Thursday
 "inicio"=>"2017-06-28",
 "final"=>"2017-06-30",
 "commit"=>"Create events"}
```

The controller action that generates the form is: eventos#forma_prog

```
# GET /eventos/forma_prog
def forma_prog
  @entrenadores = User.all
  @dias = %w[Dom Lun Mar Mie Jue Vie Sab]
  @evento = Evento.new
end
```

And the controller action that is supposed to create the events is eventos#programa:

```
# POST /eventos/programa
def programa
  entrenador = User.find(params[:entrenador])
  inicio = Date.parse(params[:inicio])
  final = Date.parse(params[:final])
  dias = params[:dias].map! {|ele| ele.to_i }
  @tipoEvento = "Entrenamiento"

  entrenador.equipos.each do |equipo|
    for @fecha in (inicio..final) do
      if dias.include?(@fecha.wday)
        @equipo_id = equipo.id
        @evento = Evento.new(evento_params)
        if !@evento.save
          flash[:error] = "No ha sido posible crear los eventos."
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I click the submit button I get an error saying **param is missing or the value is empty: evento** and the app console points to the eventos#evento_params:

```
# Never trust big bad internet, always use strong params
def evento_params
  params.require(:evento).permit(:fecha, :tipoEvento, :equipo_id, :comment, :registrado, :asistencias_attributes => [:evento_id, :player_id, :tipo, :comment])
end
```

I can see that the **params.require(:evento)** part is the problem and I guess it has something to do with the 'form_tag' I chose instead a 'form_for @evento' But I did this way because I think the form is not fully related with the @evento object for the model, please help me here...

Comment: Could you add to your question the view from where `evento_params` is getting the data?

Comment: I think you just figured it out based on your answer, just edited the question to be more explicit on the view that routes to the eventos#programa method/action which is the one connecting to evento_params. I hope I got your question right.

Comment: As i understood, `forma_prog.html.erb` sends the data to `eventos#programa`, correct? If so, then you are missing data in your form. Check updated answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: That's correct, but in my mind, at least that's what I pretend but may be failing, is that forma_prog.html.erb sets general parameters for eventos#programa to generate the model records according to those parameters, you may see that I am generating dates in the range defined in the form for the teams belonging to the trainer (Entrenador) selected in the form. I see your updated answer but the forma_prog.html.erb is not supposed to set the Evento model params but to set up boundary parameters for the controller action to generate the records params, is that possible?

Comment: I understand now, and yes, you can create an `Evento` without explicity sending its attributes in the form, but it wont work in the way you are doing it, that is, using _strong params_ (since `params` will only contain information sent by the form). So you need to set all `Evento` attributes manually. I can now see how you are setting `fecha` and `id`, but what about the other attributes (e.g. `tipoEvento`, `comment`, `registrado`, etc.), where is that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the **first problem** is that `form_tag` doesn't group all `evento` values in one key, as you are expecting.

This can be solved using `form_for` but, if you would like to keep `form_tag`, just rename the inputs with `evento[attribute]`.

Where `attribute` is the name of the parameter/field (e.g. `evento[fecha]` for your input `fecha`).

After fixing the above, the error you mention will go away, but will another one will be raised because none of the attributes needed to create an `Evento` is sent in your `form`.

So, the **second problem** is that the `form` is not sending all the parameters; you can see those needed parameters in `evento_params` method:

```
def evento_params
  params.require(:evento).permit(:fecha, :tipoEvento, :equipo_id, :comment, :registrado, :asistencias_attributes => [:evento_id, :player_id, :tipo, :comment])
end
```

This means that `evento_params` is expecting a *Parameters* hash with this structure:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"...",
  "evento"=>{
    "fecha"=>"...",
    "tipoEvento"=>"...",
    "equipo_id"=>"...",
    "comment"=>"...",
    "registrado"=>"...",
    "asistencias_attributes"=>[
      {
        evento_id=>"...",
        player_id=>"...",
        tipo=>"...",
        comment=> "..."
      }
    ],
  "commit"=>"Create events"
}
```

To fix this, you either need to send all those missing parameters, or adjust `evento_params` method to use only the ones sent by the `form`.

Comment: I did this in the eventos#programa action: '@evento = Evento.new(parametros_evento)' and defined the parametros_evento method in the private section to return the evento hash with all the required attributes. Thanks.